# Re-enabling RAID

Tags: windows-7, raid

I normally ran a 2x 1TB disk setup using RAID 0. Now I just installed a SSD and want to get access to the files which where stored on the RAID disks. I've changed the "RAID" option to AHCI in the BIOS settings for my SSD, I already installed Windows on it but Windows cannot access the disks (it says they need to be reformatted).

Is there any way to access my files while retaining the AHCI (for SSD)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for that particular RAID mode to work it needs to be enabled in the BIOS.  Depending on how your BIOS handles its RAID implementation it may be that changing that option has permanently killed your RAID array meaning that all the data stored in it is lost.

If returning that option to RAID does restore the functionality and make your RAID array work again then you are lucky but your only real option to keep the data *and* AHCI mode is to backup all of your data, set it to AHCI, then recreate your RAID array using the [Windows built-in RAID](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/36504/how-to-create-a-software-raid-array-in-windows-7/) software rather than the BIOS RAID implementation.  After that you'll need to restore your data to the array.

Answer (score 1):

For the Windows fakeraid drivers to load and recognize the array, you need to leave the mode set to RAID in the bios, not AHCI.  You should also be able to access the SSD in that mode.